# curl command not found on OSX El Cap

Tags: macos, bash, curl, osx-el-capitan

My understanding is that curl should be installed. I had tried using `curl` from the Unix command line and got the message it could not be found. I'm wondering If something I did in efforts to clean up my bash PATH has detached access to curl (and apparently sed)? The other theory I had was that the security "enhancements" for Yosemite have broken an earlier installation of curl.

```
machine-name:~ myusername$ curl -h
/usr/local/bin/curl: line 61: X/usr/local/bin/curl: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/curl: line 61: /usr/local/bin/sed: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/curl: line 65: /usr/local/bin/sed: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/curl: line 125: /usr/local/bin/curl: error: `/Users/myusername/.libs/curl' does not exist: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/curl: line 126: This script is just a wrapper for curl.: command not found
See the libtool documentation for more information.

$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/share/Scala/bin/:/Library/TeX/texbin:/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs/:/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Programs/:/Users/davidwinsemius/anaconda/bin/
```

I had tried to move `usr/local/bin` to the "front of the line" on the bash path, thinking this was the preferred location for system software. If I execute `locate curl` the output goes on for pages and I also get:

```
machine:~ myusername$ which curl
/usr/local/bin/curl
```

Although I get a man page with `$curl -h` attempting to get a version fails:

```
$usr/bin/curl -V
-bash: usr/bin/curl: No such file or directory
```

This is probably reflective of my Unix-noob gaps in knowledge about how to examine and manage links to executables. When I use the Finder/GetInfo facility on that file I see it called a Unix executable. The line that says error: "`/Users/myusername/.libs/curl' does not exist: No such file or directory" is particularly puzzling to me. I'm hoping someone can offer me some hints as to the proper command line tools to restore curl functionality to my command line.

This is occurring  on an early 2008 MacPro running OSX 10.11.4(15E65).

Comment: What happens when you type: `/usr/bin/curl -h` ?

Comment: I get a man page. So does this mean I should move /usr/bin/ in front of usr/local/bin in my path? What process does the `which` command use to determine where an executable is to be found?

Comment: And `$usr/bin/curl -V` returns: 
-bash: usr/bin/curl: No such file or directory

Comment: Got it. Thanks. I'd upvote/check  if posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curl isn't a shell script (see line 126 in the error output) and without knowing how `/usr/local/bin/curl` was installed, I suggest you move (rename) the script until you can sort out how it was installed.

Comment: using `sudo mv /usr/local/bin/curl /usr/local/bin/oldcurl` and restarting the shell allowed everything to work as desired without changing the PATH, although still think I should put `/usr/bin/` at the head of the line.